# Burninate [done]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just found a question with the [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/done) tag.  It has only 45 questions and 1 follower.  It has no tag wiki, and it would certainly not work as the only tag on a question.

It is mainly used on questions about buttons that say "done" and completed tasks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

And it's [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/done). Definitely a meta/sentence tag.

Comment: That was good teamwork.

Comment: Bah!  I was gonna post this.  Thanks for the help you two. :)

Comment: Well done. (like a burninated steak)

Comment: @MattCoubrough Great, now I want steak (though well done, not burninated). :)